# How may I get expansion of variables in the value of the FOR parameter?

Tags: windows, cmd

E.g. here

[image]

I want the last line to be

```
echo hello  1>"R:\test Chris end.m3u"
```

ANSWER from Magoo, adapted to the question case:

[image]

Note: This solution fails on filenames containing !.

Comment: I never use filenames with percent signs in them, because they are a poison character in batch files.  Is there a good reason why you do that?

Comment: The reason in this case is to include a variable. I had not realised % was poison for .BAT. A reference would be useful. In my .BATs, it seems harmless.

Comment: You will strike all sorts of problems parsing and handling a list of filenames with `%` in them, and the number of `%` signs will compound the issue.  The reason is because the batch code interprets them as environment variables, or for loop metavariables, or the start of an environment variable.

Comment: I find batch code does not by default interpret them as variables. Can you give an example?

Comment: `echo "my file %userprofile%.txt"`

Comment: Your other issue is that when using `delayed expansion` then `!` is a poison character.

Comment: @foxidrive, I see the problem in that case of a literal string, but not "all sorts of problems parsing and handling a list of filenames with % in them".

Comment: Be my guest and do what you please.  You will gain experience eventually.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
DIR %sourcedir%\*.m3u
FOR %%F IN ("%sourcedir%\test *.m3u") DO CALL SET "destfile=%%F"&ECHO hello>"!destfile!"
DIR %sourcedir%\*.m3u
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's *a* way to do it. Would be much better to try to solve the basic objective rather than fix a solution to a muddy problem.

Comment: Thanks. The basic objective is to expand variables in filenames. If you'd identify any mud you see there, I'll attempt to clarify.

Comment: This solution fails on filenames containing !.